# R- Include starting point in cumsum function

Tags: r, dataframe, cumsum, multiple-conditions

I have this `data.frame`:

```
       a b
 [1,]  1 0
 [2,]  2 0
 [3,]  3 0
 [4,]  4 0
 [5,]  5 0
 [6,]  6 1
 [7,]  7 2
 [8,]  8 3
 [9,]  9 4
[10,] 10 5
```

I want to apply `cumsum` on `column a` only when its corresponding value on `column b` is different from 0.

I tried this below but it doesn't include a starting condition on the cumsum:

```
   df_cumsum <- cbind(c(1:10), c(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5),
                       as.data.frame(ave(A[,1], A[,2] != 0, FUN=cumsum)))
```

Unfortunately, I obtain a `cumsum` over the whole column:

```
    a b  c
1   1 0  1
2   2 0  3
3   3 0  6
4   4 0 10
5   5 0 15
6   6 1  6
7   7 2 13
8   8 3 21
9   9 4 30
10 10 5 40
```

I would like to obtain:

```
    a b  c
1   1 0  0
2   2 0  0
3   3 0  0
4   4 0  0
5   5 0  0
6   6 1  6
7   7 2 13
8   8 3 21
9   9 4 30
10 10 5 40
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to create an index and update

```
i1 <- df1$b > 0
df1$c[i1] <- with(df1, cumsum(a[i1]))
```

---

Or in a single line

```
df1$c <- with(df1, cumsum(a * (b > 0)))
df1$c
#[1]  0  0  0  0  0  6 13 21 30 40
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input is `df` as shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, try this.  It zeros out any `a` value for which `b` is 0.

```
transform(df, cum = cumsum((b > 0) * a))
```

giving:

```
    a b cum
1   1 0   0
2   2 0   0
3   3 0   0
4   4 0   0
5   5 0   0
6   6 1   6
7   7 2  13
8   8 3  21
9   9 4  30
10 10 5  40
```

### Note

We assume this input shown in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
  a b
  1 0
  2 0
  3 0
  4 0
  5 0
  6 1
  7 2
  8 3
  9 4
 10 5"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

### Update

`a` and `b` had been reversed.  Have fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I really like how clean the other answers are using the `a * (b > 0)` but that can sometimes be a bit confusing for newer programers. As an alternative to this syntax you can use a vectorized `ifelse` function.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1:10), b=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5))
# One way
df$c <- cumsum(ifelse(df$b>0,df$a,0))
# Another way
df$d <- with(df,cumsum(ifelse(b>0,a,0)))
```

Comment: `ifelse(logical check, what to do if TRUE, what to do if FALSE)`